# mail.php is sending blank mails, not capturing the values from form

Tags: php, html, forms, email, post

Php code which I have used below, its sending blank emails without capturing the values

```
<?php
$name       = $_POST['name']; 
$from       = $_POST['email']; 
$subject    = $_POST['subject']; 
$message    = $_POST['message']; 
$to         = 'test@gmail.com';//replace with your email

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: {$name} <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: <{$from}>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

die;
```

Comment: What are the values? Print them out. What is $message? :) do some printr magic

Comment: show us what the HTML form looks like. This is going to be guesswork for a while.

Comment: Sidenote: I posted an answer below, however I made an important edit as to why your posted code failed and you will need to reload my answer in order to see the changes/modifications made.

Comment: I noticed you accepted my answer, then unaccepted, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** (after testing OP's code)

Your headers - [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) parameter are failing you.

I noticed you borrowed an example from the manual on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

This being your posted code:

```
$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";
$headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

but failed to use the `implode()` function from the example in the manual, being:

```
mail($to, $subject, $email, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Had you error reporting set to catch and display, you would have been presented with the following:

> Warning: mail() expects parameter 4 to be string, array given in /path/to/file.php on line x

So, you need to modify your last line to read as:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.

However, the rest of my original answer should also give you more information.

Since you did not provide us with your HTML form, I am submitting the following answer.

---

As per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php

Example #1 A simple HTML form

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
 <p>Your name: <input type="text" name="name" /></p>
 <p>Your age: <input type="text" name="age" /></p>
 <p><input type="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Example #2 Printing data from our form

```
Hi <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); ?>.
You are <?php echo (int)$_POST['age']; ?> years old.
```

If your HTML form **(which you failed to include in your question)** does not use a POST method, and/or the inputs do not bear the same name attributes as your POST arrays, then that is the reason why you are receiving blank values, or that your HTML form and PHP are inside the same file and are sending blank values on initial page load.

**Sidenote:** If your form does not explicitly use a POST method, forms default to a GET method if omitted, another possible reason why it's failing, due to probable undefined index notices you may not be seeing if [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is not set on your system and to catch and display errors/notices/warnings.

Therefore, you need to check for `empty()`'ness.

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

I.e.:

`if(!empty($_POST['var'])) { $name = $_POST['name']; }` and applying that logic to the rest of your POST arrays.

Also using a named submit button with a conditional statement wrapped around the executable code.

I.e.: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT">`

then `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}`

while checking if any of the inputs are filled/not empty.

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Displaying errors should only be done in staging, and never production.